# Pentaho Report Designer resource message

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm currently using Pentaho 5.2.

I have 1 data field that comes from the .ktr file ( *organization_name* )
I have 1 resource-label ( *org_name* ) that is text/translated in the report itself.

I was wondering how I could combine the fields as 1 field. Someone advised me to fill in the resource-message field, but I'm not sure how and the Wiki doesn't have any information: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/resource-message

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venkatesh got me on the right path, what I did to translate the labels:

**Text field with value:**

```
=CONCATENATE([ResourceMesssageFormatExpression0];" - ";[organization_name])
```

**==>** You want to add a Resource Message Format Function ( under *Data > Add Functions > Advanced functions* ) that looks toward resource-identifier 
With the Resource-Key of Pattern which contains the label: org_name

Then you can use this in the  `=CONCATENATE`

This will get the label translated.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine two fields, by using concatenate also you can achieve your requirement.

eg:-  You have two fields i.e, Field1,Field2

Now, you can combine two fields like these.

=> Take another field i.e, text field and select that text field and go to Attributes tab and find out value  and press + button and add these line.

=CONCATENATE([Field1];" - ";[Field2])

Thank you.

Comment: This won't allow me to use the resource translations hence it needs to be a resource-message i believe

Comment: what you want exactly. you want combine two fields right?

Comment: a data field from the .ktr ( query file ) and a resource-label ( something to translate from  within the report. So I can replace both fields and make 1 field. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, feel free to edit it.

Comment: In your situation resource-label as static text right?. data field from the .ktr as field in report designer right?.  You can easily make it one field. select that data field and go to Attributes tab and find out value and press + button and add these line. eg:-  =CONCATENATE([datafield];" - ";"static text meaning resource label text"). If you have any doubts feel free to ask. Thank you..

Comment: So I made the formula: =CONCATENATE("org_name";" - ";[organization_name])

But the org_name doesn't get translated because there is no resource identified, even with a resource-message field it doesn't work.

Comment: Here resource label meaning some static text. I have one doubt org_name( resource-lable) showing some text in report designer or not?

Comment: I'm not to sure what you are asking here? What do you mean with ' showing some text in report designer '? the original org_name I had was resource label with the resource-identifier linked to the resources-file for translations in other languages.